# Could not find Numpy Scipy in IDLE

Tags: python, numpy, idle-python

I am given Ubuntu 14.04 from work even though I always used windows in the past. I installed `python-numpy` and `python-scipy` from the Ubuntu software center. From the look of it, I think I already install the two packages. I can import them in IPython. However, it seems that IDLE could not find these package.

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Could anyone explain why this is the case and how to fix it, please? Thank you! I am completely new to ubuntu.

As suggested in the comments, I got the following.

IDLE:

```
['', 
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

IPython:

```
['',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Clearly the paths are different. What is more troubling is that they are different version of Python. I must have done something wrong. My intention was to use 3.4 version in fact. I guess I need to add numpy and etc. to this version. How do I do it, please? Thank you!

Comment: Please check the content of [`sys.path`](//docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in both IPython and IDLE and compare it with the location of the files of the `numpy` package (check with `dpkg --listfiles python-numpy`). There are most likely discrepancies between them. Please [edit] your question to include your findings.

Comment: Where to type sys.path, please? In IPython and IDLE? It did not seem to work.

Comment: Yes, in IPython and IDLE. You need to `import sys` first of course.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you. I am not so good at Python, either. Please see my updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your IPython and IDLE editions are based on different major versions of Python (2 and 3 respectively). For your projects you need to use either one or the other for consistency. The relevant package names for the two Python versions are:

- Python 2: `idle ipython python-numpy python-scipy`
- Python 3: `idle3 ipython3 python3-numpy python3-scipy`

You can install all of them side by side, but you'll get into trouble if you try to run the same piece of software on both except for the most simple cases.

Comment: That is, I need to write whatever I need in just one of them. Right? I read that Python3 has more functionality, right?

Comment: I want to use a similar command line as follows: sudo apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-matplotlib ipython3 ipython3-notebook python3-pandas python3-sympy python3-nose

Comment: Some of those packages do not seem to exist, for example, python3-sympy. Do you happen to know the correct names, please? Thank you!

Comment: Python 3 "cleans up" many things in the standard library from earlier Python, that the developers consider badly designed. Also, Python 2 will likely become obsolete earlier than Python 3. If you can, use Python 3. Unfortunately you or somebody else involved with your Python scripts might need to use software without Python 3 support.

Comment: Unfortunately there is [no SymPy package for Python 3 in Debian](//bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712924) or Ubuntu. You can use the outdated package from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~takluyver/+archive/ubuntu/python3) or [install it manually](https://github.com/sympy/sympy#usage-in-python-3) per the documentation by the SymPy developers.